# How to use MGSpotyViewController with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to use [MGSpotyViewController](https://github.com/matteogobbi/MGSpotyViewController) on my swift project but I can't seem to make it work.

I have installed it via cocoa pods, I configured a ViewController on Storyboard to use this class and this is how my code looks like now:

```
import UIKit
import MGSpotyViewController

class profileTableViewController: MGSpotyViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    overView = myOverView()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func myOverView() -> UIView{
    let view = UIView(frame: self.overView.bounds)

    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(view.center.x-50.0, view.center.y-60.0, 100.0, 100.0))
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "profile")!
    imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    imageView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width/2.0

    view.addSubview(view)

    return view
}
}
```

The thing is that I don't know to configure the delegate methods, they are not being recognized by XCode.

Anyone had configured this controller with swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You view controller should implement the data source & delegate methods equivalent to whats 's the pod's readme, something like:

```
func spotyViewController(_ viewController: MGSpotyViewController, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    ...
}
func spotyViewController(_ viewController: MGSpotyViewController, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell? {
    ...
}
func spotyViewController(_ viewController: MGSpotyViewController, heightForHeaderInSection section: NSInteger) -> CGFloat {
    ...
}
func spotyViewController:(_ viewController: MGSpotyViewController, titleForHeaderInSection section: NSInteger) -> String? {
    ...
}
```

Then either do this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.dataSource = self
self.delegate = self
```

or use your storyboard/nib to link those connections back to the view controller.

Comment: Thanks, I think that would solve the table view related issues. The other problem that I am having is that I don't know how to initialize it from a storyboard, because the documentation only says how to do it from code, not from a storyboard. I tried with initWithCoder and calling inside of it: super.init(mainImage: UIImage(named: "profile")!) but I got the following error: "fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(mainImage:tableScrollingType:)' for class '***.profileTableViewController'"

Comment: Initialize *what* from a storyboard, your view controller? Don't call `init` from an `initWithCoder`, only call `super.initWithCoder` from your overridden `initWithCoder`. If you want to share common init code you have to put that into your own method you call from both init paths. Its common though to defer all view controller initialization to `viewDidLoad`. Also, `awakeFromNib` get called sometime before `viewDidLoad`, you can override that method and put some initialization in there too.

Comment: I kind of understand what you said. The code example that the guy wrote to initialize the view from code using objective-c is the following: `MGViewController *spotyViewController = [[MGViewController alloc] initWithMainImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"example"]];` and then you would do something like this (pseudo code): `[self presentViewController:spotyViewController];` How can I make the same thing when the view controller is set up on a storyboard? I am not being able to call `initWithMainImage`. Make sense? Thanks for your help by the way

Comment: You must set the image sometime after initialization, call `setMainImage` in `awakeFromNib` or `viewDidLoad`. Don't skip the Guides sections of Apple's docs, such as "View Controller Programming Guide for iOS" which do cover some topics that cross outside the reference for any one particular class, such as using view controllers with storyboards.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that of that too, but inside the `initWithMainImage` method are other initialization code

Comment: If it does essential stuff only in `initWithMainImage` then it doesn't support instantiation from a storyboard. To double-check: make an un-subclassed `MGSpotyViewController` in storyboard, use breakpoint in debugger to see that `initWithMainImage` is never called. File an issue or fork & fix yourself.